# Different definitions of the Grothendieck universe

Tags: logic, set-theory

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) the Grothendieck universe is defined as a set $U$ with the following properties:

- if $X\in Y\in U$, then $X\in U$,
- if $X,Y\in U$, then $\{X,Y\}\in U$,
- if $X\in U$, then $2^X\in U$,
- if $I\in U$ and $\{X_i;\ i\in I\}\subseteq U$, then $\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\in U$.

Recently I found another definition at [this website](http://cantorsattic.info/Inaccessible#Universes):
a set $U$ is a Grothendieck universe if it has the following properties:

- if $X\in Y\in U$, then $X\in U$,
- if $X,Y\in U$, then $\{X,Y\}\in U$,
- if $X\in U$, then $2^X\in U$,
- if $X\in U$, then $\cup X\in U$

(the difference is in the last property).

I suppose these two definitions are equivalent, but I don't understand why. Can anybody explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second definition is wrong.  For instance, the set $V_{\omega+\omega}$ satisfies the second definition, but not the first.  It fails to satisfy the first definition since it contains $\omega$ and every element of the family $(V_{\omega+n})_{n\in\omega}$ but it does not contain their union (namely, $V_{\omega+\omega}$ itself).  However, this union cannot be written as the union of any element of $V_{\omega+\omega}$ (and indeed the union of any element of $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is still an element of $V_{\omega+\omega}$) so this does not violate the second definition.

Comment: Yup, just caught that.

Comment: Thank you, Eric!

Answer (score 4):

I misread the second definition! They are in fact not equivalent, and the second definition is **wrong**. To see this, note that $V_{\omega+\omega}$ satisfies Definition $2$ but not Definition $1$.

I think it's much better to rephrase the last clause as follows:

> If $D\in U$, $C\subseteq U$, and there is a surjection $D\rightarrow C$, then $C\in U$.

This amounts to saying that $U$ satisfies replacement *as calculated in $V$* (this is stronger than merely $U$ satisfying the replacement axioms internally). Together with the other rules, this implies that if $U$ is a Grothendieck universe containing $\omega$ then $U=V_\alpha$ for $\alpha$ a **regular strong limit cardinal**, or **(strongly) inaccessible cardinal**. So Grothendieck universes are really just (small) large cardinals in disguise.

Comment: Noah, this explains why the first definition implies the second one. But the inverse implication (which actually is a real problem) is not clear.

Comment: Noah, this is used only in the implication 
$$
\text{Definition 1 $\Rightarrow$ Definition 2}.
$$
This does not prove the inverse imlication: 
$$
\text{Definition 2 $\Rightarrow$ Definition 1}
$$

Comment: There must be a lemma, something like this:

Lemma. If $U$ satisfies Definition 2, then for each element $X\in U$ and for each surjection $f:X\to Y$ the set $Y$ is also an element of $U$: $Y\in U$.

Is this true?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Argh, you're right - see my edit. That said your lemma is not true of *either* definition as phrased (you need $Y\subseteq U$ as an additional hypothesis - otherwise, for $Z$ arbitrary think about $Y=\{Z\}$ and then apply the first clause of the definition).

Comment: Noah, yes, I forgot to write that $Y\subseteq U$. So I thought that maybe you mean that this proposition is true: Lemma. If $U$ satisfies Definition 2, then for each element $X\in U$ and for each surjection $f:X\to Y$, with $Y\subseteq U$, the set $Y$ is also an element of $U$: $Y\in U$. Excuse me.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov yes, that statement is correct.